# How do I connect the database of pc1 to pc2 without installing the database itself into pc 2

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, networking

So, we are trying to do a project on connecting the database from pc1 to pc2 without installing the database in pc2. The concept of the idea is that PC2 is the application server where we run the program using Visual Studio while PC1 is the data server which contains the database (SQL Server) where pc2 gets its data from. I'm trying to search if homegroup could fix this problem but to no avail, I still can't find any solutions. I am only a beginner on networking and database management and I really hope someone could help me out with this problem. Thank you! :)

Comment: SQL Server what? CE? Express? Enterprise? And what does “connect” mean? You want to copy the database from one machine to another? You want to replicate changes on one machine to the other? Singly or bidirectionally? Or do you want only one database? We don't have your development environment here; you'll have to describe it to us.

Comment: We're using SQL Server Express. Well, the program is composed of a textbox wherein if you input the code of a certain product, it will retrieve the details in the data server. I want to have only one centralized database where they get the details of the product from but I'm not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use remote server by setting remote server in connection string like:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

if SQl server has instances configured then connection string will be like:

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

But **make sure you have enabled remote connections in SQL Server**.

If it is not, you can enable it like :

1.

[image]

  2.

[image]

Make sure firewall on server is not blocking requests.

Sources:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx